# php - utilizar <br/> como ENTERS na textarea

Tags: php

Eu gostava de obter a informação sobre:

- Quando uma pessoa faz um Enter na textarea, o proprio código deveria inserir um "br>" na mysqli, dando assim uma alinha abaixo.

Como poderei realizar esta forma?

Comment: da uma olha da http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php